# Tag Synonym: Changes <--> Change Management

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I've been adding some wiki definitions to our tags...

We have a small number of questions tagged as [changes](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changes) but suggest that this term is a bit ambiguous, and recommend the (unused to date] tag *change-management* as a better tag, with *changes* as a synonym?

This would align with other tags, such as:

- [project-management](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management)
- [time-management](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-management)
- etc

Answer (score 2):

One term that applies to these questions is [scope-creep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep), which according to Wikipedia is:

> Scope creep (also called requirement creep and feature creep) in project management refers to uncontrolled changes or continuous growth in a project’s scope. This phenomenon can occur when the scope of a project is not properly defined, documented, or controlled. It is generally considered a negative occurrence, to be avoided.

Whereas Wikipedia defines [change-management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_management), which also may apply, as follows (*Emphasis is mine*):

> Change management is an approach to transitioning individuals, teams, and organizations to a desired future state. In some project management contexts, change management refers to a project management process wherein ***changes to a project are formally introduced and approved.***

Thus, the project management side of the change management definition also applies to two of the three questions tagged by [changes](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changes). One of them isn't about any kind of change and will likely have the tag removed completely.

When we do a Google search for "changes", we get [David Bowie's "Changes"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pl3vxEudif8) song as our very first result!  It's a cool listen -- go ahead and listen to it and enjoy -- but it's not really related to what we do here.  Searching for "change management" or "scope creep" give us results more closely related to these topics.

Thus, it sounds like [change-management](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-management) and/or [scope-creep](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope-creep) would be a better choice for these questions, both for readability and search engine optimization. After all, we want folks to be able to do their Google searches and find us next to *relevant* results. Sorry, David Bowie.

**Here is what I suggest:**

- [At what point is it no longer a "Free Change"](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1/at-what-point-is-it-no-longer-a-free-change) - [scope-creep](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope-creep) or [change-management](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-management)
- [How do I deal with clients who ask me to change the design every few days?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/103/how-do-i-deal-with-clients-who-ask-me-to-change-the-design-every-few-days) - [change-management](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/change-management) (arguably, [scope-creep](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope-creep) may work as well)
- [Agile methodologies when developing software as a freelance?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/381/agile-methodologies-when-developing-software-as-a-freelance) - I'm not sure I see how either tag applies here, as this question is about using agile methodologies, not managing scope creep or change.

As for [changes](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/changes), for David Bowie's sake, maybe we can keep it as a synonym, or just get rid of it altogether. With only a few questions with a tag, creating synonyms at this point may be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say no. Those three tags describe their current questions quite nicely, and create a category that seems to work quite nicely. Feel free to disagree, buy that's my two cents

Comment: So you don't think [tag:change-management] makes more sense than [tag:changes]. Fair enough.....

Comment: As I said, just an opinion. If the community doesn't like the idea, they're free to down-vote me and upvote you.